# XML grab attribute from specific element node

Tags: c#, xml

If `myVariable = "Element"` then give me the attribute inside that element.

XML:

```
<Products>
<Equity>
    <servers>
       <serverEQ>server1</serverEQ>
       <serverEQ>server2</serverEQ>
       <serverEQ>server3</serverEQ>
    </servers>
<sitesE>
      <sitesEQ sitePathEQ="\Logs\W3SVC1"><nameEQ>SystemAdmin Site</nameEQ></sitesEQ>
      <sitesEQ sitePathEQ="\Logs\W3SVC3"><nameEQ>Direct Access Site</nameEQ></sitesEQ>
      <sitesEQ sitePathEQ="\Logs\W3SVC4"><nameEQ>Redirect Site</nameEQ></sitesEQ>
      <sitesEQ sitePathEQ="\Logs\W3SVC5"><nameEQ>Download Site</nameEQ></sitesEQ>
</sitesE>
</Equity>
.
.
.
</Products>
```

For example: If `myVariable = "Direct Access Site"` give me `\Logs\W3SVC3` as my output.

Comment: I found Hossein Narimani Rad's answer most useful.  Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not clear what exactly you want but this may helps:

```
var myVariable = "Direct Access Site";
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(your file);
var result = doc.Descendants("sitesEQ")
               .Where(i => i.Element("nameEQ").Value == myVariable )
               .Select(i => i.Attribute("sitePathEQ").Value);

foreach (string item in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```